# Append " .Parent" attribute to awesome grid using jquery

Tags: asp.net-mvc-awesome

I want to append a `.Parent` attribute to my awesome mvc grid using jquery on dropdown change. How would I do this?

Comment: why do you need this

Comment: I have multiple grids in my project. And a partial view with drop downs, instead of appending .Parent attribute in each grid I want to generate it dynamically on drop down change, so which ever gird it is , it will get the drop down value

Comment: this still doesn't explain why do you need this dynamically; you have a dropdown and a few grids, if you set parent on all of them when the dropdown changes value they will reload

Comment: you could also use the grid api, instead of Parent binding to perform search